# Jenkins 2.18 withCredentials doesnt work in pipeline (Credentials Binding Plugin)

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

When I tried `withCredentials` in pipeline with the following code:

```
node('master'){
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordBinding', credentialsId: '6c7ca6d2-bb14-46e2-bcba-c0a09f8b9fc5', variable: 'USER']]) {
        sh "echo $USER"
    }
}
```

I got the error result like:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: USERNAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:24)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:361)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:226)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I tried create normal job with the following configs:
[jenkins config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaF7S.png)

Then got the right result like:

```
[test2] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3350033971174776171.sh
+ echo jerry:123
jerry:123
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I don't know where I made wrong. The pipeline code was generated by pipeline syntax. It should work.

I also tried using jenkins 2.7.2, but got the exactly same error.

I don't know whether a jenkins bug or my mistake. Please help...Thank you..

Comment: I found my mistake. should use single-quotes not double... But I found another issue was when I echo USER, only display `****`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is. According to the documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin): "Any secrets in the build log will be masked automatically."

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was because my Jenkins Project had a space in it. Will never make that mistake again! (I probably will)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't posted and chosen your own answer yet. I'll post mine anyway.

In the documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin).

> // note: single quotes prevent Groovy interpolation; expansion is by Bourne Shell, which is what you want

This one took me some time to understand, too. Here's how I did it while calling a shell script `script.sh`. I used single quotes to let the shell interpolate the variables when the script executes, just like what you did. If it helps, you can think of it as late interpolation.

```
stage('<stage>') {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '<id>', usernameVariable: '<var1>', passwordVariable: '<var2>']]) {
        sh './script.sh'
    }
}
```

And the variables `<var1>` and `<var2>` will be available in your script.sh as environment variables. I was trying to do a `docker login` in my `script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Will still print ****, which is cool.
echo $<var1>

# Will interpolate to their values correctly.
docker login -u $<var1> -p $<var2>
```